# How to get the count of different categories from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

My categories are unknown(dynamic). I want to get the count of records in each categories and the category name to that count to implement in the graph. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 select count(*) as cat_count, category from table_name group by category
```

Comment: +1 for naming the count column.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select count(*), category from <table> group by category
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(id) as count, category_name from category group by category_name
```